# Trying to call svn.exe from batch file called by .NET webpage - odd results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svn, batch-file, windows-server-2008

**The situation:** I have a mvc.net web page which, when called, runs a batch file on my server using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start and cmd.exe. The batch file contains a line that runs "svn.exe update myfilepath" and should therefore update the files on the server.

**What's happening?**
- the batch file is running, but the call to svn.exe does nothing, nor produces any error messages.
- if I run the batch file by double clicking, the svn command DOES run successfully.

I guess this is a security issue, but I'm no expert on this and I cannot make any headway.

The site is hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2 and the app pool is using the ApplicationPoolIdentity system. I have tried running the app pool as Network Service and also adding Network Service as a user that can Read/Execute to svn.exe.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be proxy related. It's possible that you access the Internet via a proxy, but that the user profile for the app pool identity isn't configured like this. You may need to use a domain account that you can log on as in order to create a suitable user profile. You will also need to make sure IIS is loading the profile by ticking the appropriate option.

(Another possibility is that the working directory for the process you are starting is not set correctly to the root of your Subversion working copy. We've established this wasn't the problem in your case.)

Comment: Hi David, thanks for answering. I am a total newbie at windows accounts, so don't really know what a domain account is. Does it help you if I say that I am testing this by using remote desktop into the server and then calling my webpage at http://localhost/...?

Comment: In that case you probably don't have a domain. Just set up a local user account on that box, one for which you know the password, make sure that has all the rights you need, then log on to the box as that user and make sure you can run the Subversion command from the command line. If you can't access the SVN server, and it's not on one of your machines but on the Internet, then it's likely the proxy as I've suggested.

Comment: I think I've tried that. I can log in to the server using RDP and my admin account. My batch file (and the SVN command) runs successfully if I run it from this account. The problem occurs only if the batch file is run by the webpage, presumably running under the app-pool user. The main problem is I don't get any error messages at all so diagnosis is very difficult.

Comment: Exactly. You must log on AS THE APP POOL USER to test this. So since you don't have the Network Service password, you must create an account for this.

Comment: Ok, I've now tried this to no avail. I added a new user, and used aspnet_Regiis to set it up with IIS. Changed the app pool to use this new user. Then enabled Remote Desktop with this user. Logged in via Remote Desktop with new user. Exactly the same problem: Successfully ran the batch file by double clicking. When I try to call the batch file from my webpage, everything in the batch file runs except for the svn.exe command. No error messages.

Comment: Now thinking - how about a different approach altogether. All I want is to be able to hit a link from my phone or laptop and for the files to be updated - this must be a common scenario?

Comment: Are you setting the working directory to the root of your Subversion working copy?

Comment: Ok I have got it to work with the new user I created by setting  "Load User Profile" to TRUE in IIS Advanced settings for the app pool. Hopefully this won't have any other security impact.

Comment: Glad you got it working - so it was profile related, I've edited the answer to include that option.

Comment: If you know why this is, and have anything else to add, please submit it as an answer and I'll award it to you.